# Difference-in-Sargan test in R

Tags: r, stata

How can I calculate the Difference-in-Sargan statistic (or C-statistic) in R?
In Stata, I would do something like this to get this statistic for pred2 (and see if it is exogenous, assuming that all instruments inst1-3 are exogenous):

```
ivreg2 y (pred1 = inst1 inst2 inst3) pred2, orthog(pred2)
```

What would the corresponding code in R be (ideally using the "ivreg" package in R)?